# Javascript Printing Issue (IE | Iframes | PDF)

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, printing

Currently - I have a View that populates an Iframe with a PDF, and I am attempting to print the contents of the Iframe (the PDF) using Javascript.

Everything seems to be working as it should in nearly every browser with the exception of IE. I have tried several different methods and you can see my current one below:

**Print View:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function (){
    //Grabs the Iframe   
    var ifr = document.getElementById("PDF");

    //PDF is completely loaded. (.load() wasn't working properly with PDFs)
    ifr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (ifr.readyState == 'complete'){ 
            ifr.contentWindow.focus(); 
            ifr.contentWindow.print(); 
        } 
    }
});
</script>

<html>
    <body style='margin: 0; overflow: hidden;'>
       <iframe src='URL' width="100%" height="100%" id="PDF" name="PDF"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above appears to work in IE, as it launches a print dialog box once the PDF has been loaded, however upon selecting a printing option, nothing happens.

The same result happens in Chrome and Firefox (print dialog etc.) however, the PDF is actually printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF plug-in has taken over the iframe so the print functionality has to come from the PDF, not the browser.

Comment: Is this the case? As the same functionality works in Chrome and Firefox, I just find it odd that it the print dialog would display, and yet it still would not print. Are there any ways to automatically print through the plug-in?